# A group of order $56$ with a unique Sylow $2$-group is either nilpotent or its Sylow $2$-group is $\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})^3$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group of order $56$, $Q$ a normal Sylow $2$-group and $P$ a Sylow $7$-group.  Show either $G \cong Q \times P$ or $Q \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

The hint given is to note that $P$ acts on $Q \setminus \{e\}$ by conjugation and to show that this action is either trivial or transitive.

I understand the hint; if the action is trivial, then the elements of $Q$ and $P$ commute with each other, which means $QP$ is an internal direct sum with $56$ elements, whence $G = QP \cong Q \times P$.  If the action is transitive, we know that $Q$ has some element of order $2$; therefore every element of $Q \setminus \{e\}$ has order $2$ and $Q$ is isomorphic to the given group.

Comment: What is your question? It seems like you see how the hint proves the proposition. Are you asking how to prove the hint (how to prove the action must be trivial or transitive)?

Comment: Right, I don't know how to prove the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set $Q\setminus\{e\}$ has 7 elements. Let $S \leq P$ be the set of elements of $P$ that commute with some specific $q \in Q\setminus\{e\}$. If $S=\{e\}$, then by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, the orbit of $q$ under the action of $P$ has size $[P:S]=7$. In other words, $Q\setminus\{e\}$ is itself the orbit of $q$, and so $P$ acts transitively on $Q\setminus \{e\}$. This is true no matter which $q \in Q\setminus\{e\}$ is chosen, as long as $S=\{e\}$. Hence we may assume that $S \neq \{e\}$ for any $q \in Q\setminus \{e\}$ (the only remaining case). However, the only possibility for $S$ other than $\{e\}$ is $S=P$, since $|P|=7$ (Lagrange's theorem). In other words, the only remaining case is where every element of $P$ commutes with every element of $Q \setminus \{e\}$ (and obviously also with every element of $\{e\}$). This exactly means the action of $P$ on $Q \setminus\{e\}$ is trivial, and also that $G=P \times Q$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that there are only $5$ groups of order $8$. So if you can show that $7$ does not divide the order of any of their automorphism groups, except for the elementary abelian one, then you know the action is trivial. Otherwse, the $2$-Sylow is elementary abelian.